# Manga where all the characters were human/animal hybrids

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga a while ago. All the characters were half-human, half-animal. The main character was half-human, half-crow, his main weapon was this hatchet-like thing attached to a chain that he would throw.

One of the secondary characters was a half-human, half-fish that was always trying to get the character to shut up and also super grumpy.

A second side character was a half-human, half-bear that was introduced when he killed someone because he couldn’t control his animal side.

A third side character that was introduced pretty late was a half-human, half-bat kid whose mom was killed by her dad and she lived because she was hiding in the forest.

Answer (score 7):

This is [*+Anima*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%2BAnima) (AKA Purasu Anima, AKA プラス アニマ)

> Beings who possess animal-like powers walk among humans in this
>   alternate universe. These mysterious mutants, the +Anima, are shunned
>   by society. Four outcasts in particular — Cooro, **a boy with crow-like
>   powers**; Husky, **a fish-boy**; Senri, **a bear +Anima**; and a girl named
>   Nana, who wields **the power of the bat** — search for others like
>   themselves while trying to gain acceptance in a world cruel to anyone
>   or anything that is different.

...

> In the Mukai's original short story, Cooro is much more violent, has wild behavior, and wields **a small hatchet.**

[image]

Comment: Yes, +Anime was it, I was looking everywhere, I’m so stupid cus I thought it was called Anime+. thank you

Comment: @sirwiggleton - Don't forget to upvote and click the "accept" tick to the left of my answer...